# pyrogram пересылка поста из канала в канал (telegram)

Tags: python, pyrogram

Python + Pyrogram.
Всем привет. Пишу парсер вк с последующей отправкой в канал телеграм.
Организованно это так, что получаем с вк картинку - > отправляем в отдельный канал для предосмотра -> если картинка подходит, то нужно отправить эту картинку в основной канал.

Проблема в том, что я не могу придумать метод как организовать пересылку картинки из отдельного канал в основной.
Есть предположения, что нужно как то получить ID последнего поста из отдельного канала и пересылать этот пост методом Message.forward(). Но я не могу найти информацию как это сделать..

Comment: Единственная мысль - сохранять в файлик данные последнего поста, и потом это всё проверять. Можете попробовать

Comment: @YDCdeveloper, проблема то и заключается в этом, что я не знаю как получить данные последнего поста). Только что пришла идея, попробовать отправлять в канал сообщение, получать id этого сообщения и минусовать 1. По логике получиться ID поста, который нужен. Попробую попозже..

Comment: Хорошо, думаю что ответ полезен